# Setting multisite in WAMP

Tags: multi-sites

I have created folder structure like below:

Main Drupal: www_d8multisite_com

```
Subsite1: www_d8multisite_com/sites/default/ms1
Subsite2: www_d8multisite_com/sites/default/ms2
```

And put the sites.php inside

```
www_d8multisite_com/sites/sites.php
```

and defined my multisite like below:

```
$sites['www.d8ms1.com'] = 'ms1';
$sites['www.d8ms1.com'] = 'ms2';
```

And put the settings.php in both subsite folders like below:

```
Subsite1: www_d8multisite_com/sites/default/ms1/settings.php
Subsite2: www_d8multisite_com/sites/default/ms2/settings.php
```

Then I setup my virtual host like below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "H:/wamp/www/www_d8multisite_com"
    ServerName www.d8ms1.com
    ServerAlias www.d8ms1.com
    ErrorLog "logs/www.d8ms1.com.error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/www.d8ms1.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "H:/wamp/www/www_d8multisite_com"
    ServerName www.d8ms2.com
    ServerAlias www.d8ms2.com
    ErrorLog "logs/www.d8ms2.com.error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/www.d8ms2.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Still my multiste is not working. If I'm trying to access any of the subsites(www.d8ms1.com or www.d8ms2.com) it only pointing to base site. I mean site is still loading from base www_d8multisite_com. not from sub folders.

Am I doing something wrong in the configuration? or I missed any step?

Comment: <VirtualHost www.d8ms1.com:80>

Answer (score 0):

I have never really used multi site much, but I have read the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multisite-drupal/multi-site-sharing-the-same-code-base) multiple times nevertheless.

It always was my understanding that the `default` folder was reserved for the default site, and that all other folders should be placed next to it, not inside of it.

Next to that, the documentation implies that your folder name should match a certain pattern, based on the site url.

Instead of using `www_d8multisite_com/sites/default/ms1` I'd try using `www_d8multisite_com/sites/d8ms1.com` instead.

Comment: Yes, domain folders should be in `/sites` and not `/sites/default`. The `default` folder is the one Drupal will use if no other match is found. For instance, if you only ran single site, you would use `/sites/default`.